# Is it faster to have code (around 30 lines) inside of nested functions or its faster to call the code without a nested function

Tags: javascript, performance

say i have a block of code such as

```
for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        str = pieceData[piece][rotation]
        char = str.substr(k, 1);

        if (char == 1) {
            c.fillStyle = pieceColours[piece]
            c.fillRect(x + (i * 20), y + (j * 20), 20, 20)
            c.fill()
        } else {
            c.fillStyle = 'green'
            if (x + (i * 20) > 180) {
                c.fillStyle = 'red'
            }
            c.fillRect(x + (i * 20), y + (j * 20), 20, 20)
            c.stroke()
        }
        k++
    }
}
k = 0
```

would it slow down if i call it within a  nested function such as

```
function pieceGen() {

    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            str = pieceData[piece][rotation]
            char = str.substr(k, 1);

            if (char == 1) {
                c.fillStyle = pieceColours[piece]
                c.fillRect(x + (i * 20), y + (j * 20), 20, 20)
                c.fill()
            } else {
                c.fillStyle = 'green'
                if (x + (i * 20) > 180) {
                    c.fillStyle = 'red'
                }
                c.fillRect(x + (i * 20), y + (j * 20), 20, 20)
                c.stroke()
            }
            k++
        }
    }
    k = 0
}
//________________________________________________________________________

function animate() {
    pieceGen()
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}
```

i need to take this into consideration due my laptops poor performance and will it slow down if I use more and more nested functions?

Comment: Calling a function has a *very slight overhead*, but it's almost never something to worry about, especially on modern browsers - code readability is more important

Comment: If you want to gain, focus on the code itself. For instance, don't use global variables but define them with local scope, use function parameters, and assign `str` outside of the loops (since it is invariant of it)

Comment: There are sites such as https://jsbench.me/ which provide you with an easy way to compare performance. You might be also interested in how things are across different browsers.

Comment: If you wouldn't use globals but declare all your variables (`j`, `str`, `char`, `k`) as local with `var`, the function probably would even have a performance advantage.

Comment: Why not just test it?

Comment: It is always better to write functions. More than overhead it is more maintainable code, helps others to understand code better. Also use proper variable and function names. Ideally many good books suggests your function shouldn’t be more than 4-5 lines.

Comment: If your function is very tiny, still it’s better to have functions. JS now provides arrow functions which comes in very handy to use.

Comment: my variables are already declared in the beginning of the script (Not included)

Answer (score 3):

Function calling have a very insignificant overhead in javascript, use them freely as they make your code cleaner

Comment: + having code organized in functions enables the JIT compiler to actually optimize them (and possibly even inline the code in the calling function), whereas too big functions are simply ignored for any optimization. There's little one can do to improve the speed of some code that will outperform the optimizations the JIT compiler can do to your code; if they are applicable to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are function objects. In JavaScript, anything that is not a primitive type ( undefined, null,boolean, number, or string) is an object.
This means, in your second case, you will have the following overhead:

- an object will be created containing the function's description
- a memory address will be allocated that will store the function's context(closure)

So two extras:

- an extra object with a few bytes in it (the function)
- an extra closure

Neither of those really matter in terms of performance.

Code readability & encapsulation will serve you a lot better, go for it ! You should always think about performance, that's true, but functions are building blocks of javascript and you should use them.

Comment: OP isn't creating a closure in the loop anywhere?

Comment: loops create a closure on each iteration: http://www.teknically-speaking.com/2013/01/closures-in-loops-javascript-gotchas.html

Comment: Um, no. Function definitions create closures, nothing else. Function definitions in loops have to be treated carefully because of the scope in the loop. But the OP doesn't have any functions inside his loop!

Comment: So are you saying my code is slightly unreadable, what are some reccomendations for readability

Comment: I'm not saying it's unreadable, it's not enough of it to make such a statement. You asked if there's any noticeable perf. drop if you encapsulate your logic in a function and then call that function. The short answer is : there is some overhead but it's so little that encapsulation is probably a good idea to make the code more readable & modular. You would also be able to reuse that function elsewhere.